# Tile draws pixels from adjacent tiles

Tags: unity, tilemap

Whenever I try to draw from the tile palette, this is the result. why does this happen? I have tried messing around with the palette, how the sprite editor has sliced the tiles and played around with the anchors and cell sizes, but to no avail. I found a few threads about offset tiles in the tile map, but it doesn't help at all. Any leads as to why this happens?

[image]

Comment: Somehow fixed it by tweaking the Tilemap's anchor to X: 0.5, Y: 0.5. Unsure as to why, but it worked. Sprite resolution was 4000x2400 and pixel per unit 100. Slicing was centered to 100x100.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Please post your solution as an answer to the question instead of leaving it as a comment - it makes the information easier for others to find & edit.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow fixed it by tweaking the Tilemap's anchor to X: 0.5, Y: 0.5. Unsure as to why, but it worked. Sprite resolution was 4000x2400 and pixel per unit 100. Slicing was centered to 100x100.